# How long would it take to guess this combination?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I'm working on a license key algorythm and I would like to know, if there's any way to calculate, how long would it take average computer to guess a code with `5908888918826932944906` possible combinations (5 blocks of 4 uppercase letters and numbers)... (Also I hope, that I have calculated the number of combinations right :D )

Comment: It depends on how long one try takes and how fast the computer is.

Comment: Well let's suppose we have a computer with one i7 processor (about 69 GFLOPS), and we have as much time as we want, how long would that take?

Comment: How long does it take to check one combination?

Comment: mmmhh.. I don't think that math.stackexchange is the right place for such a question. Maybe here: http://superuser.com/

Comment: @Dasherman actually we only need to know how long it takes to check how long it takes to check one combination (how fast is the computer is then an implicit parameter of this time)

Comment: That's hard to tell, It takes about 1.419ms (average of about 1000 iterations) to generate random key and compare it to an existing one...

Comment: @JacobS. But you don't generate them randomly isn't it? You try them all and wait until you found the correct one or am I missing something?

Comment: I've just quicky edited the generator to measure this, so yes, I'm generating them randomly, but it probably won't take much longer to do it systematically... PHP is slow...

Comment: Okay, I made it check all the possible combinations systematically and it takes about 1.2ms to check one combination...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we want to find a key with $d$ characters. For each character we have $n$ different possibilities. The computer takes $t$ seconds to check one possible combination. Then:

- There are $n^d$ different possibilities
- The time needed to check **every** possibility is given by $t\cdot n^d$

So the minimum time required to find the correct combination is $t$ (if the first solution is correct) and the maximum time required is $t \cdot n^d$ (if the last solution is correct).

In you case: $d = 4 \cdot 5 = 20$ and $n = 10 + 26=36$ and $t$ depends on your computer/program.

Comment: ... and the average time is $t \cdot n^d/2$.  If $d=20$ and $n=36$ and $t = 1.2\; ms$, the average time would be 
about $2.5 \times 10^{20}$ years.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose, that is enough :D Thank you all.

Comment: But this is assuming there is exactly one correct key.  If the company sells a lot of copies of their product, each with a different key, then there should be lots of valid keys.

Comment: Yes, but the key is generated at the moment of purchase and deactivated once used, so there is a really low chance of guessing an active one...